# functionname redefinition; different basic types

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm getting the following error: 
error C2371: 'BinarySearchTree::isComplete' : redefinition; different basic types

This is my header file:

```
    #ifndef BinarySearchTree_H
#define BinarySearchTree_H

#include <iostream>
#include "Queue.h"
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
struct TreeNode;

enum OrderType {PRE_ORDER, IN_ORDER, POST_ORDER};

template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
  BinarySearchTree();                     // Constructor.
  ~BinarySearchTree();                    // Destructor.
  BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree& originalTree);  // Copy constructor.
  void operator=(const BinarySearchTree& originalTree);
  void MakeEmpty();
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool IsFull() const;
  int LengthIs() const;
  void RetrieveItem(T& item, bool& found) const;
  void InsertItem(T item);
  void DeleteItem(T item);
  void ResetTree(OrderType order);
  void GetNextItem(T& item, OrderType order,bool& finished);
  void Print(std::ostream& outFile, OrderType order) const;
  int countMaxDepth();
  void arrayBST(T * a);
  bool isComplete();
  bool isComplete(TreeNode* node);


private:
  TreeNode<T>* root;
  Queue<T> preQue;
  Queue<T> inQue;
  Queue<T> postQue;

};

template <class T>
int CountNodes(TreeNode<T>* tree);

template <class T>
void GetPredecessor(TreeNode<T>* tree, T& data);

template <class T>
void Destroy(TreeNode<T>*& tree);

template <class T>
void CopyTree(TreeNode<T>*& copy, const TreeNode<T>* originalTree);

template <class T>
void PreOrder(TreeNode<T>*, Queue<T>&);

template <class T>
void InOrder(TreeNode<T>*, Queue<T>&);

template <class T>
void PostOrder(TreeNode<T>*, Queue<T>&);

template <class T>
void PrintTree(TreeNode<T>* tree, std::ostream& outFile);

template <class T>
int maxDepth(TreeNode<T>* tree);



#endif
```

This is my implementation file:

```
    #include "BinarySearchTree.h"
#include "Queue.h"
#include "Queue.cpp"

template <class T>
struct TreeNode
{
  T info;
  TreeNode<T>* left;
  TreeNode<T>* right;
};

template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::IsFull() const
// Returns true if the free store has no room for another node
//  and false otherwise.
{
  TreeNode<T>* location;
  try
  {
    location = new TreeNode<T>;
    delete location;
    return false;
  }
  catch(std::bad_alloc exception)
  {
    return true;
  }
}

template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::IsEmpty() const
// Returns true if the tree is empty and false otherwise.
{
    return root == NULL;
}

template <class T>
int BinarySearchTree<T>::LengthIs() const
// Calls the recursive function CountNodes to count the
//  nodes in the tree.
{
  return CountNodes(root);
}

template <class T>
int CountNodes(TreeNode<T>* tree)
// Post: Returns the number of nodes in the tree.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
    return 0;
  else
    return CountNodes(tree->left) + CountNodes(tree->right) + 1;
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::RetrieveItem(T& item, bool& found) const
// Calls recursive function Retrieve to search the tree for item.
{
  Retrieve(root, item, found);
}

template <class T>
void Retrieve(TreeNode<T>* tree,
     T& item, bool& found)
// Recursively searches tree for item.
// Post: If there is an element someItem whose key matches item's,
//       found is true and item is set to a copy of someItem;
//       otherwise, found is false and item is unchanged.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
    found = false;                      // item is not found.
  else if (item < tree->info)
    Retrieve(tree->left, item, found); // Search left subtree.
  else if (item > tree->info)
    Retrieve(tree->right, item, found);// Search right subtree.
  else
  {
    item = tree->info;                 // item is found.
    found = true;
  }
}


template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::InsertItem(T item)
// Calls the recursive function Insert to insert item into tree.
{
  Insert(root, item);
}

template <class T>
void Insert(TreeNode<T>*& tree, T item)
// Inserts item into tree.
// Post: item is in tree; search property is maintained.
{
  if (tree == NULL)
  {// Insertion place found.
    tree = new TreeNode<T>;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->info = item;
  }
  else if (item < tree->info)
    Insert(tree->left, item);     // Insert in left subtree.
  else
    Insert(tree->right, item);    // Insert in right subtree.
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::DeleteItem(T item)
// Calls the recursive function Delete to delete item from tree.
{
  Delete(root, item);
}

template <class T>
void Delete(TreeNode<T>*& tree, T item)
// Deletes item from tree.
// Post:  item is not in tree.
{
  if (item < tree->info)
    Delete(tree->left, item);    // Look in left subtree.
  else if (item > tree->info)
    Delete(tree->right, item);   // Look in right subtree.
  else
    DeleteNode(tree);            // Node found; call DeleteNode.
}

template <class T>
void DeleteNode(TreeNode<T>*& tree)
// Deletes the node pointed to by tree.
// Post: The user's data in the node pointed to by tree is no
//       longer in the tree.  If tree is a leaf node or has only one
//       non-NULL child pointer, the node pointed to by tree is
//       deleted; otherwise, the user's data is replaced by its
//       logical predecessor and the predecessor's node is deleted.
{
  T data;
  TreeNode<T>* tempPtr;

  tempPtr = tree;
  if (tree->left == NULL)
  {
    tree = tree->right;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  else if (tree->right == NULL)
  {
    tree = tree->left;
    delete tempPtr;
  }
  else
  {
    GetPredecessor(tree->left, data);
    tree->info = data;
    Delete(tree->left, data);  // Delete predecessor node.
  }
}

template <class T>
void GetPredecessor(TreeNode<T>* tree, T& data)
// Sets data to the info member of the rightmost node in tree.
{
  while (tree->right != NULL)
    tree = tree->right;
  data = tree->info;
}

template <class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree()
{
  root = NULL;
}

template <class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::~BinarySearchTree()
// Calls recursive function Destroy to destroy the tree.
{
  Destroy(root);
}

template <class T>
void Destroy(TreeNode<T>*& tree)
// Post: tree is empty; nodes have been deallocated.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    Destroy(tree->left);
    Destroy(tree->right);
    delete tree;
  }
}

template <class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree(const BinarySearchTree<T>& originalTree)
// Calls the recursive function CopyTree to copy originalTree
//  into root.
{
  CopyTree(root, originalTree.root);
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::operator=
     (const BinarySearchTree<T>& originalTree)
// Calls the recursive function CopyTree to copy originalTree
// into root.
{
  {
    if (&originalTree == this)
      return;              // Ignore assigning self to self.
    Destroy(root);         // Deallocate existing tree nodes.
    CopyTree(root, originalTree.root);
  }
}

template <class T>
void CopyTree(TreeNode<T>*& copy,
     const TreeNode<T>* originalTree)
// Post: copy is the root of a tree that is a duplicate
//       of originalTree.
{
  if (originalTree == NULL)
    copy = NULL;
  else
  {
    copy = new TreeNode<T>;
    copy->info = originalTree->info;
    CopyTree(copy->left, originalTree->left);
    CopyTree(copy->right, originalTree->right);
  }
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::ResetTree(OrderType order)
// Calls a function to create a queue of the tree elements in
// the desired order.
{
  switch (order)
  {
    case PRE_ORDER : PreOrder(root, preQue);
                     break;
    case IN_ORDER  : InOrder(root, inQue);
                     break;
    case POST_ORDER: PostOrder(root, postQue);
                     break;
  }
}

template <class T>
void PreOrder(TreeNode<T>* tree,
     Queue<T>& preQue)
// Post: preQue contains the tree items in preorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    preQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
    PreOrder(tree->left, preQue);
    PreOrder(tree->right, preQue);
  }
}

template <class T>
void InOrder(TreeNode<T>* tree, Queue<T>& inQue)
// Post: inQue contains the tree items in inorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    InOrder(tree->left, inQue);
    inQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
    InOrder(tree->right, inQue);
  }
}

template <class T>
void PostOrder(TreeNode<T>* tree,
     Queue<T>& postQue)
// Post: postQue contains the tree items in postorder.
{
  if (tree != NULL)
  {
    PostOrder(tree->left, postQue);
    PostOrder(tree->right, postQue);
    postQue.Enqueue(tree->info);
  }
}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::GetNextItem(T& item,
     OrderType order, bool& finished)
// Returns the next item in the desired order.
// Post: For the desired order, item is the next item in the queue.
//       If item is the last one in the queue, finished is true;
//       otherwise, finished is false.
{
  finished = false;
  switch (order)
  {
    case PRE_ORDER  : preQue.Dequeue(item);
                      if (preQue.IsEmpty())
                        finished = true;
                      break;
    case IN_ORDER   : inQue.Dequeue(item);
                      if (inQue.IsEmpty())
                       finished = true;
                     break;
    case POST_ORDER: postQue.Dequeue(item);
                     if (postQue.IsEmpty())
                       finished = true;
                     break;
  }
}

template <class T>
void PrintTree(TreeNode<T>* tree, std::ostream& outFile, OrderType order)
// Prints info member of items in tree in sorted order on outFile.
{
    switch (order)
    {
    case PRE_ORDER :
        if (tree != NULL)
        {
            outFile << tree->info;
            PrintTree(tree->left, outFile ,order);   // Print left subtree.
            PrintTree(tree->right, outFile, order);  // Print right subtree.
        }
        break;
    case IN_ORDER :
        if (tree != NULL)
        {

            PrintTree(tree->left, outFile, order);   // Print left subtree.
            outFile << tree->info;
            PrintTree(tree->right, outFile, order);  // Print right subtree.
        }
        break;
    case POST_ORDER :
        if (tree != NULL)
        {

            PrintTree(tree->left, outFile, order);   // Print left subtree.
            PrintTree(tree->right, outFile, order);  // Print right subtree.
            outFile << tree->info;
        }
        break;
    default:;
    }

}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::Print(std::ostream& outFile, OrderType order) const
// Calls recursive function Print to print items in the tree.
{
  PrintTree(root, outFile, order);
  outFile << endl;
 }

template <class T>
int BinarySearchTree<T>::countMaxDepth()
{
    return maxDepth(root)-1;
}

template <class T>
int maxDepth(TreeNode<T>* tree)
{
    if(tree == NULL)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int lDepth = maxDepth(tree->left);
        int rDepth = maxDepth(tree->right);
        if(lDepth > rDepth )
            return lDepth+1;
        else 
            return rDepth+1;
    }

}

template <class T>
void BinarySearchTree<T>::arrayBST(T * a)
{
    T temp;
    bool f;
    a = new T(CountNodes(root));
    ResetTree(IN_ORDER);
    for (int i = 0; i < LengthIs(); i++)
    {
        GetNextItem(temp, IN_ORDER, f);
        a[i] = temp;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::isComplete()
{
    return isComplete(root);
}

template <class T>
bool BinarySearchTree<T>::isComplete(TreeNode<T>* node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
        return true;
    if ((node->left == NULL && node->right != NULL) || (node->left != NULL && node->right == NULL))
        return false;
    return isComplete(node->left) && isComplete(node->right);
}
```

I've done some googling but it's been no use. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: `TreeNode* node`. TreeNode is not a type, it's a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the problem is that in the function declaration it should be:

```
template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
  //...
  bool isComplete(TreeNode<T>* node);
};
```

Or else the compiler will think it is a pointer to a non-template `TreeNode` type.

Maybe this non-template type does exist somewhere in your code. Or maybe you have more error messages that relate to that line. Or maybe your including of the `.cpp` file is messing with the linker, as the contents of that `.cpp` file may be compiled twice.

Comment: very difficult to spot :)

Comment: Thanks alot. I knew I was missing something obvious but I spent so much time trying to fix it without noticing that.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not `#include` one `.cpp` file into another.
- You will have to move your class template's functions into the header from the `.cpp` file. See also http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/separate-template-class-defn-from-decl.html.
- I see references to pointers (e.g., `TreeNode<T>*&`). That looks fishy.